# What could be the reason for getting 500 server error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

Im trying to integrate stripe payment using axios with node.js but at the end Im getting back an error message: Request failed with status code 500, although in the request payload I do see a  token data filled properly.

here is my node.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") require("dotenv").config();

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

  app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Server running on port " + port);
});

app.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  const body = {
    source: req.body.token.id,
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: "eur",
  };

  stripe.charges.create(body, (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
    if (stripeErr) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: stripeErr });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({ success: stripeRes });
    }
  });
});
```

and here is my client side code using axios library and stripe-checkout pre-built component

````
  const priceForStripe = price * 100;
  const publishableKey = "pk_test_i28ouERO9Dli1OlxDdGM7HFA00hCEjnkrw";

  const onToken = (token) => {
    axios({
      url: "/payment",
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      data:{
        amount: priceForStripe,
        token,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        alert("Payment was successfull !!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Payment error:", error);
        alert("There was an issue with your payment");
      });
  };

  return (
    <StripeCheckout
      label="PAY NOW"
      name="Shibukas&Co"
      billingAddress
      shippingAddress
      image="https://sendeyo.com/up/d/f3eb2117da"
      description={`Your total price is €${price}`}
      amount={priceForStripe}
      panelLabel="Pay Now"
      token={onToken}
      stripeKey={publishableKey}
    />
  );
};```
````

Comment: have you done: console.log(stripeErr, stripeRes); in stripe.charges.create()? And what does it print?

Comment: after the console.log of stripeErr, I found out the issue, my secret key was is live mode but it had to be in test mode. Thanks a lot, mate ??